# Validate field in repeated grid with webservice

Tags: orbeon

I am using a webservice through an action in a field to retrieve some aditional data as well as validate the user input. The validation is done by storing in a instance the validation status and make the input field to check that the code is not present to be valid. This works correctly as long as I don't try to use a repeated grid. When a repeated grid is used the same instance is used for all the repeated fields. The webservice data is loaded correctly independendtly, but the validation is shared between all of them. How can I adjust the code to work properly in repeated grids?

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
     xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
     xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
     xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
     xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
     xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
     xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder">
<xh:head>
    <xh:title>repeated_ws</xh:title>
    <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">

        <!-- Main instance -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <form>
                <section-1>
                    <grid-4>
                        <grid-4-iteration>
                            <userId/>
                            <name/>
                            <address/>
                        </grid-4-iteration>
                    </grid-4>

                </section-1>
            </form>
        </xf:instance>

        <xf:instance id="repeatable-uid-instance">
            <valid/>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Bindings -->
        <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
            <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">
                <xf:bind id="grid-4-bind" ref="grid-4" name="grid-4">
                    <xf:bind id="grid-4-iteration-bind" ref="grid-4-iteration" name="grid-4-iteration">
                        <xf:bind id="userId-bind" ref="userId" name="userId">
                            <xf:constraint id="validation-9-validation"
                                           value="instance('repeatable-uid-instance')/valid != 'not exist'"/>
                        </xf:bind>
                        <xf:bind id="name-bind" ref="name" name="name" readonly="true()"/>
                        <xf:bind id="address-bind" ref="address" name="address" readonly="true()"/>
                    </xf:bind>
                </xf:bind>

            </xf:bind>
        </xf:bind>

        <!-- Metadata -->
        <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <metadata>
                <application-name>test</application-name>
                <form-name>repeated_ws</form-name>
                <title xml:lang="en">repeated_ws</title>
                <description xml:lang="en"/>
                <singleton>false</singleton>
            </metadata>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Attachments -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <attachments>
                <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
            </attachments>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- All form resources -->
        <!-- Don't make readonly by default in case a service modifies the resources -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:readonly="false" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <resources>
                <resource xml:lang="en">
                    <userId>
                        <label>userId</label>
                        <hint/>
                        <alert>custom error</alert>
                    </userId>
                    <name>
                        <label>name</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </name>
                    <address>
                        <label>address</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </address>
                    <section-1>
                        <label>Untitled Section</label>
                    </section-1>

                </resource>
            </resources>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Utility instances for services -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <request/>
        </xf:instance>

        <xf:instance id="fr-service-response-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <response/>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="grid-4-template">
            <grid-4-iteration>
                <userId/>
                <name/>
                <address/>
            </grid-4-iteration>
        </xf:instance>

        <xf:instance id="get-user-data-instance" class="fr-service"
                     xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <body xmlns:secure="java:org.orbeon.oxf.util.SecureUtils"
                  xmlns:frf="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fr.FormRunner"
                  xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                  xmlns:fbf="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fb.FormBuilder">&lt;bsn/&gt;</body>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:submission id="get-user-data-submission" class="fr-service"
                       ref="instance('fr-service-request-instance')"
                       resource="http://localhost:8082/rest/getUserData"
                       method="post"
                       serialization="application/xml"
                       mediatype="application/xml"
                       replace="instance"
                       instance="fr-service-response-instance"/>
        <xf:action id="call-get-user-data-binding">
            <!-- React to event... on control... -->
            <xf:action ev:event="xforms-value-changed xforms-enabled" ev:observer="userId-control"
                       if="true()">
                <!-- Service to call -->
                <xf:send submission="get-user-data-submission"/>
            </xf:action>
            <!-- Request actions -->
            <xf:action ev:event="xforms-submit" ev:observer="get-user-data-submission">
                <!-- Get reference to initial request -->
                <xf:var name="request-instance-name" value="'get-user-data-instance'" as="xs:string"/>
                <!-- Copy over to read-write request instance -->
                <xf:insert ref="instance('fr-service-request-instance')"
                           origin="saxon:parse(instance($request-instance-name))"/>
                <!--<xf:insert ref="instance('fr-service-request-instance')" origin="instance($request-instance-name)"/>-->
                <!-- Set values if needed -->
                <xf:action context="instance('fr-service-request-instance')">
                    <xf:action class="fr-set-service-value-action">
                        <xf:var name="control-name" value="'userId'"/>
                        <xf:var name="path" value="/bsn"/>
                    </xf:action>
                    <!-- Setvalue actions will be here -->
                </xf:action>
            </xf:action>
            <!-- Response actions -->
            <xf:action ev:event="xforms-submit-done" ev:observer="get-user-data-submission"
                       context="instance('fr-service-response-instance')">
                <xf:action class="fr-set-control-value-action">
                    <xf:var name="control-name" value="'name'"/>
                    <xf:var name="control-value" value="/data/name"/>
                </xf:action>
                <xf:action class="fr-set-control-value-action">
                    <xf:var name="control-name" value="'address'"/>
                    <xf:var name="control-value" value="/data/address"/>
                </xf:action>
                               <xf:insert origin="instance('fr-service-response-instance')"
                           ref="instance('repeatable-uid-instance')"/>
                <!-- Response actions will be here -->
            </xf:action>
        </xf:action>
    </xf:model>
</xh:head>
<xh:body>
    <fr:view>
        <fr:body xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
                 xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
                 xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline">
            <fr:section id="section-1-control" bind="section-1-bind">
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
                <fr:grid id="grid-4-grid" bind="grid-4-bind" repeat="content" min="1"
                         template="instance('grid-4-template')">
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:input id="userId-control" bind="userId-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/userId/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/userId/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$form-resources/userId/alert" validation="validation-9-validation"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>



                            </xf:input>
                        </xh:td>
                    </xh:tr>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:input id="name-control" bind="name-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/name/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/name/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>


                            </xf:input>
                        </xh:td>
                    </xh:tr>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:input id="address-control" bind="address-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/address/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/address/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>


                            </xf:input>
                        </xh:td>
                    </xh:tr>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
        </fr:body>
    </fr:view>
</xh:body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Orbeon Forms are you using? Since 4.5, [control resolution follows repeats in actions](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1527), so the result from your service should only change the `name` and `address` of the current iteration, i.e. the one in which the `userId` changed and triggered the action to run, which seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm using the latest version. It's not a problem that the fields `name` and `address` change correctly with the current iteration, which they do. What I want to accomplish is to validate the `userId` field. Right now I'm doing it by storing the validation state in a instance but that won't work with current iteration.

Comment: @JorgeIzquierdoCiges Then what about you add a hidden field in the iteration to store the result of the web service, and use that field in your validation? (Using a separate instance when you have repeats is almost always a bad idea.)

Comment: but if i do that the hidden field would still appear on the result XML which is not desired.

Comment: @JorgeIzquierdoCiges If the field is hidden, it won't show up in the UI. Or am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: it won't show in the UI but any content in it would appear on XML data of the form later.

Comment: @JorgeIzquierdoCiges True, then you'll have that "unnecessary" element in the XML data. I imagine that this might be a problem for you when you submit the data to services? Can you imagine of a way to remove it before then? I'm saying that, because the alternative, which is to keep it in a separate instance, is quite complicated, as it requires that you keep that other instance in sync with the main instance whenever deletions/additions are made, which can be tricky to implement and quite error prone.